# How to import a project with only its Java and XML files?

Tags: android, android-studio

New to android studio and trying to import a project but I only have .java, .xml, gradle, and .idea and .iml files.

Comment: If you do not have complete project , then create a new android project in android studio keeping the packages name similar ( or change it if you want and refactor classes), and copy `.java file` , `.xml` file and `.gradle` . you don't need to copy `.idea` and `.iml`

Comment: the apps build.gradle file correct?

Comment: Yes you can go through steps suggested by @Jimmy